# readFASTA VS read.fasta

Tags: r, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I am new to R and having problems with biostrings function readFASTA. The latest version of biostrings in `R 3.0.1` is different. The previous version seems to be doing the job. hence i started using function `read.fasta` in from seqin R. I am reading DNA sequences from a fasta file.

`readFASTA` read the sequence as follows

```
[[9999]]

[[9999]]$desc

[1] "9320"


[[9999]]$seq

[1]

"TCCCCTGAAATTCCCCC"
```

now `read.fasta` is reading the sequence as

```
[[4746]]

[1] "AACACAACCTCATTCCC"
```

using the `$` operator in the previous version I could split the sequence and geneid
but with the present version I don't know what to do. Is there anyway I could get the same output as I was getting from `readFASTA`.

Comment: `?str` - R Documentation: Compactly Display the Structure of an Arbitrary R Object

Comment: you could also ask http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `read.fasta` or the `biostrings` package for guidance? If they've changed the way the output is structured there should be some advice provided either in the package changelog since it is likely to break other peoples' existing workflows.

Comment: Yeah I was able to resolve the problem by adjusting the parameters of the read.fasta function. Thank you